# StreamCorruptedException while trying to parse a byte array in Java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, low-level

I'm writing an Android app, trying to parse some binary data received via Bluetooth, containing various signed and unsigned 1-4 byte integers. I'm given to understand that the best (or possibly only) way to interpret bytes as unsigned numbers is via an input stream. My code is:

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
ObjectInput in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
```

The second line, for some reason, throws a StreamCorruptedException with no data in it. What am I doing wrong? Also how is it conceptually possible to "corrupt" a bunch of bytes?

Comment: I strongly suspect you want DataInputStream rather than ObjectInputStream...

Comment: @JonSkeet You appear to be correct! Might want to put that as an answer rather than comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the data has been written by `ObjectOutputStream`, you shouldn't use `ObjectInputStream` - that's very specific to Java's binary serialization. If this is just binary data, 4 bytes for a 32-bit integer etc, then you probably want [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) instead - but you should validate that your data is big-endian, which is what `DataInputStream` will handle it.